# Correct definition of frequency density - histograms

Tags: statistics, terminology

What is the correct definition of frequency density?

According to a textbook I am teaching from, frequency density is merely *proportional* to $\dfrac{\text{frequency}}{\text{class width}}$, and could be a multiple of $\dfrac{\text{frequency}}{\text{class width}}$.

This seems wrong to me. For example, one would not say that population density could be $2\times\dfrac{\text{population}}{\text{area}}$. So why is it OK to do this with frequency density? Is the textbook misusing the term 'frequency density'?

Comment: Six years after publication, the publisher has finally corrected their mistake and rewritten the histograms chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequency density is defined as the **ratio of the frequency of a class to its width**. There is no proportionality constant or anything of that sort.

I feel [this page](https://undergroundmathematics.org/glossary/frequency-density) will help you. I am afraid the book is wrong.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you.